# Internationalization when used to translate for Chinese language

Tags: java, internationalization

I am having trouble with the Internationalization in my java project.

When translating words from English to Chinese some characters are rendered as question marks.

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    String lang="ch";
    String country="CH";
    Locale l=new Locale(lang,country);      
    ResourceBundle r = ResourceBundle.getBundle("com.neomandi.prototype/Bundle_ch_CH",l);
    String val = r.getString("average"); 
    System.out.println(st);     
}
```

I am not able to paste the Chinese word in eclipse. When i do so it changes to `\u5E73\u5747`.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like there is problem with configuration.
For pasting unicode character in eclipse change the encoding to unicode.
For output display unicode character in output, update run configuration.[image]