# Reading currency Symbol as string in Java

Tags: java, csv, currency, iso

I actually need to import a **csv** file for currency in my *pgAdmin* database. My file is as follows;

[image]

My code is as follows, using an ISO-8859-1 format.

```
        File fileDir = new File(fileName);       
        FileInputStream fis= new FileInputStream(fileDir);
        InputStreamReader isr= new InputStreamReader(fis, "ISO-8859-1");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);            
        String line;
        line = br.readLine();
        String[] arrayHeader = line.split(";");         
        size = arrayHeader.length;       

        if(size==expectedSize){
             //check header 
            String header[] = {"Currency_ISO", "Currency_Label", "Currency_Symbol"};
            for(int i=0;i<header.length;i++){
                if(arrayHeader[i].trim().equals(header[i])){
                    fileStatus = true; 
                    sResult = "File Status: Valid <br/> "; 
                }
                else{
                    fileStatus = false;
                    sResult = "File Status: Invalid <br/> "; 
                    break;
                }
            }
        }else{
            fileStatus = false;  
            sResult = "File Status: Invalid <br/> ";    
        }       

        if(fileStatus){     

             while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                 String[] arrayData = line.split(";", -1);

                //create object 
                objCurrency = new clsCurrency(); 

                if(arrayData[0] != "" && !arrayData[0].isEmpty() && arrayData[0].trim() != ""){

                    objCurrency.setsCurrencyIso(arrayData[0].trim());
                }else{
                    objCurrency.setsCurrencyIso(null);
                }

                if(arrayData[1] != "" && !arrayData[1].isEmpty() && arrayData[1].trim() != ""){                                         
                    objCurrency.setsCurrencyLabel(arrayData[1].trim());
                }else{
                    objCurrency.setsCurrencyLabel(null);
                }

                if(arrayData[2] != "" && !arrayData[2].isEmpty() && arrayData[2].trim() != ""){
                System.out.println("setsLocalCurrencySymbol: " + arrayData[2]);
                    objCurrency.setsCurrencySymbol(arrayData[2].trim());
                }else{
                    objCurrency.setsCurrencySymbol(null);
                }

                lstCurrencyImported.add(objCurrency);

            }//end while
```

As you can see, I have a `System.out.Println()` to check the values being read for the symbols. But the main issue is that the Symbol is not being read correctly. It is returning a `?` instead. See the println below;

```
[stdout] (default task-7) setsCurrencySymbol: ?
```

I tried changing the format to `UTF-8` or `UTF-16`, but in vain.
I saw online that there is the **currency** class for Java, but problem is that I need to read it from the csv directly, and I don't think the users know the code for each currency.

Any idea how do I proceed from here guys?

Comment: Have a look 
: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43472991/internationalization-when-used-to-translate-for-chinese-language/43486746#43486746

Answer (score 3):

Your CSV file cannot possibly be ISO-8859-1 if it contains the Euro symbol. The Euro symbol does not exist in ISO-8859-1. It was added in [ISO-8859-15](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-15).

The way to proceed is, first, find out what encoding your CSV file is actually using. Then, configure the Java `InputStreamReader` to use that encoding.

Comment: Please have a look at your file with a hex editor. If the Euro sign reads as 0x80, the file is Windows CP 1252, if it's 0xa4, then the encoding is ISO-8859-15.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but how do I know the encoding. The users just opens the csv in a notepad and update it. In notepad I don't think the specify the encoding.
I tried changing the encoding to ISO-8859-15, but still in vain.

Comment: You can set the encoding when saving with Notepad, but I think by default it uses Windows-1252 (which it calls 'ANSI').

Comment: But in Windows-1252, it accepts the symbols, right?

Comment: Both $ and € *exist* in Windows-1252, yes, although I have no way of knowing for sure if that is the encoding your file is in.

Answer (score 2):

- **ISO-8859-1** aka Latin-1 does not contain the € symbol.
- **ISO-8859-15** was an extension *with* the € symbol.
- **Windows-1252** / **CP-1252** (Code-Page) aka Windows Latin-1 replaces what is still called ISO-8859-1 in browsers (even officially in HTML5).

As **Windows-1252** also contains more characters than ISO-8859-15 like comma like quotes and such, best use that for a correct reading of the text.

The text then is correct (in Unicode) in a String.

*Alternative, when the user's PC determines which charset is used, and the
software runs there, you can use `Charset.defaultCharset()` as argument to the InputStreamReader, or simply not give the argument.*

Displaying in the string in the console involves again a conversion to the default, operating system charset. Likely also Windows-1252 in Windows, in the US. It the charset does not know a € it will be converted to a ?, but it will be there in the string.

You could write it to a UTF-8 file for instance.

Comment: Thnx. I tried saving the csv as UTF-8 and reading it with the same encoding.. now even in the column name, its reading `?Currency_ISO` instead of `Currency_ISO`.
Don't understand why it is adding a '?'

Comment: That first one maybe stems from a BOM (begin-of-file-mark) character, a zero-width space that is redundant, but which Windows recognizes the file as UTF-8 in Notepad. Maybe Windows-1252 is easiest here, though I prefer UTF-8 (without BOM) too.